# Why update would let query cost enhance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I added a serial id column `new_id` into an existed table, and the serial number need to be ordered by `created_at`.

I use the SQL query below to create and update `new_id`

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.deals ADD COLUMN new_id BIGINT;
create sequence deals_new_id_seq;


UPDATE public.deals
  SET new_id = t.new_id
from (
   select id, nextval('deals_new_id_seq') as new_id
   from deals
   order by "created_at"
) t
where t.id = deals.id;
```

I result of this process is well, but I used `EXPALIN` to get query plan and the cost become double.

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM public.deals ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 100
```

Before:

```
Limit  (cost=27661.84..27673.51 rows=100 width=118)
->  Gather Merge  (cost=27661.84..93253.38 rows=562174 width=118)
Workers Planned: 2
->  Sort  (cost=26661.81..27364.53 rows=281087 width=118)
Sort Key: created_at
->  Parallel Seq Scan on deals  (cost=0.00..15918.87 rows=281087 width=118)
```

After:

```
Limit  (cost=41330.84..41342.51 rows=100 width=118)
->  Gather Merge  (cost=41330.84..106922.38 rows=562174 width=118)
Workers Planned: 2
->  Sort  (cost=40330.81..41033.53 rows=281087 width=118)
Sort Key: created_at
->  Parallel Seq Scan on deals  (cost=0.00..29587.87 rows=281087 width=118)
```

I want to know why the cost would be higher than initial situation
and Is there a way to down the cost?

Comment: why do you need a new id anyway, what purpose has it?

Comment: @nbk The serial number of pk is good for my app to manage

Comment: I would have used `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of a sequence. Its behavior is consistent and well documented.

Comment: To reduce the cost of the main query I would add the index: `create index ix1 on public.deals (created_at);`.

Comment: The likely reason for the cost increase is that the table's row structure is different between the _before_ and _after_ cases: there is an additional column in the _after_ case. There's not much more that can be determined without the table's description. What was the cost estimate after the column was added but before it was populated? The question assumes that the `UPDATE` triggered the increased cost; however, there were two changes made: one to structure, and one to content.